# Rails: have link create a product and redirect to the edit product page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an auction site and have been scratching my head trying to figure out how to best deal with auction/product creation. What I have come up with, and it may be a horrible idea, is to have a `List Item` link that, when clicked, posts to the `create` action for the `auctions` controller and then redirects to the edit page for that auction.

The reason I want to do this is because I feel it will make adding photos to the product at creation time easier and I can save the state of the auction so that they can come back and finish it later if they want.

**The question:**

How do I make a link post to the create action and then redirect to the edit page for the newly created item?

Let me know if there are any specific files you need to see, but I don't really have any code to go off of since I haven't made my create and edit actions yet or the routes

Comment: `<%=link_to 'Auction item', items_path, method: :post %>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form_for in your view, you can change the destination url and set the method to post like this:

```
<%= form_for @auction, { :url => auction_path, :method => :post } do |f| %>
... Create your form ...
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller:

```
def create
  @auction = Auction.new(params.require(:auction).permit(< list your parameters here>))
  if @auction.valid?
    @auction.save
    flash[:notice] = 'New Auction created successfully.'
    redirect_to 'edit'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```